# Reason: Input dispatching timed out (ActivityRecord{ecaa4d2 u0 com../.ui..HomeActivity t3} does not have a focused window)

Tags: anr

I got an ANR crash report like this

```
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (ActivityRecord{ecaa4d2 u0 /.ui..HomeActivity t3} does not have a focused window)
```

and trace shows:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x718474c0 self=0xe4a05410
  | sysTid=1277 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xecc1d470
  | state=S schedstat=( 10298604300 1305185943 17035 ) utm=910 stm=119 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff787000-0xff789000 stackSize=8192KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 0007272c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  native: #01 pc 00044209  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (epoll_wait+16)
  native: #02 pc 00011bad  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+128)
  native: #03 pc 00011ad3  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+62)
  native: #04 pc 000b9eb9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, int)+26)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Does anyone meet it before? Appreciate for any advice.

Binders in main thread group looks like:

```
"Binder:1277_1" prio=5 tid=14 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12f403e0 self=0xe4a06210
  | sysTid=1342 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xc1bcd1c0
  | state=S schedstat=( 167585904 86193790 337 ) utm=14 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xc1ad2000-0xc1ad4000 stackSize=1008KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00071654  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+12)
  native: #01 pc 0003f76f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+26)
```

```
"Binder:1277_2" prio=5 tid=15 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12f40458 self=0xe4a13410
  | sysTid=1343 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xc1acc1c0
  | state=S schedstat=( 219541537 179474996 433 ) utm=16 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xc19d1000-0xc19d3000 stackSize=1008KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00071654  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+12)
  native: #01 pc 0003f76f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+26)
```